# How to allocate N students into n number of groups ensuring each of the student has worked with all student?

Tags: excel, combinations, permutation

I am looking for a guide or algorithm or anything that will point me into right direction. Let me explain what I want with an example:

Suppose there are 40 students. I should ensure that each of the student has worked with every other student through out their academic year. Groups get changed every 2 weeks. I have the liberty to use any language (although I would like the end-product be in excel as the end-user is familiar and I don't have to create any UI) but I am not able to think of the logic. The persons in the group is mostly pre-decided. Mostly it is between 3-5. If it is 3, 40/3 = 12 groups of 3 and 1 group of 4. Now we need to shuffle the students so that say in Pth shuffle each student should have worked with every other student in their batch. If it is impossible to achieve in P tries, maximize the same. P is mostly limited by the number of subjects they take and hence cannot be changed.

What I tried so far was something like brute-force. It is not efficient and takes a lot of tries to ensure every student has worked with other plus the next iteration is very predictable (i would like it be pseudo-random, if poss). Logic I tried is

```
1st Pass - Group 1: 1 to 3, 3 to 6, 6 to 9, .. Group P: 37 to 40
2nd Pass - Group 1: 2 to 4,... Group P: 38 to 40, 1
3rd Pass - Group 1: 3 to 5, ... Group P: 39, 40 , 1 2
```

Any help is highly appreciated :)

Comment: *Welcome to [so]!* This is a site where programmers *write their own code* and share issues with a ***specific* problem** after trying to solve it on their own. If you have a particular issue after [researching](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592) existing answers, please [edit] your post to share some background info and a **[mcve] of your code** and relevant data. More tips here: *"[ask]"* and in the [help/on-topic], as well as this [checklist](//codeblog.jonskeet.uk/stack-overflow-question-checklist/) from the sites' top user.  Good luck!

Comment: Do a search on here - there are several combination or permutation questions...

Comment: Also there are several websites that will help you plan combinations if you search google for "combination generator".  Will you have enough lessons to match up all 780 possible pairs of students?